# iphone ShareKit - How to "check in" in facebook places using sharekit?

Tags: iphone, sharekit

Hello All ,
             I have been using ShareKit for almost all the stuffs regarding social sharing from the iphone Apps . Now I want to make the check in functionality for facebook available in my App . I don't see any way to do that using ShareKit .

1) Is it possible to do so using ShareKit ?

2) If not how do I go for that ?

Thank You !!!

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out how to implement check in with the Facebook API. I was wondering if you had any tips or tutorials. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cureently, there is no way to check in using SHKFacebook in the ShareKit library. You'll have to research the Facebook API and implement the method yourself in ShareKit. The best place to start would be the [Facebook API documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

Comment: Thanks Mark , I am just done with this . I totally removed the facebook sharing classes from the ShareKit and integrated the ios Facebook sdk in my project . This way , for other social sharing like twitter etc I dont need to rebuild every thing from scratch and for facebook part I can use the ios facebook sdk classes ( which are   bit a work at the start but then you get more flexibilty .. ) .... Thanks :)